# Remove Gnome safely? (after installing Unity)

Tags: apt, gnome, unity, uninstall, .desktop

There [are](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154373/is-it-safe-to-remove-gnome-shell) already [some](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1396786/is-it-safe-to-remove-gnome-software) other threads about removing Gnome.

But my concern did not seem to be addressed anywhere, I think.

I installed Unity and couldn't be happier. Now the Gnome packages are totally useless.

To remove Gnome and friends, the command

```
apt remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop gnome-shell
```

asks if it's ok to remove

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   gdm3 gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
   gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng gnome-shell-extension-prefs
   gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-shell-extensions
   ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-session
```

the last 3 are a bit worrying

```
---> ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-session
```

I want to keep running a desktop with Unity!

Questions

- why should these 3 removed since Unity is still installed to keep a GUI desktop working?
- can I go ahead anyway? (the 3 packages being only used by Gnome?)
- if not, how to remove Gnome safely? (and keep Unity / desktop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Those are meta packages [What is the difference between a meta-package and a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66257/what-is-the-difference-between-a-meta-package-and-a-package)
- Yes
- `apt remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop gnome-shell` is the command.
  I tend to remove the desktop and  then drop to a console session (on F2) and then install the deesktop I want. You can always redo the command you used to install Unity.

Comment: It worked, but the funny thing is that `df -h` reports more / space used after the 'remove' compared to before and `apt clean` & `autoremove` didn't help much.

Comment: Did you remove the apt caching?

Comment: Like the comment said, "apt clean" (or even autoclean) didn't help much (didn't get back to the space before the remove)